# Some users still see parked domain page three days after setting DNS records

Tags: domains, wordpress, dns

It's been 3 days now and some users cannot connect to the website (they just see the generic Related Links domain page). MOST users can, but when I try on Verizon Wireless or AT&T Wireless, neither of those work to connect to the website.

Is there something wrong? Should it really be taking this long to propagate?

I just removed an AAAA record that was pointed to `2607:f1c0:100f:f000:0:0:0:270` but I don't think that's fixed anything.
http://wahoowriters.com is the website.
[image: DNS Settings]

Comment: You do not seem to have a DNS problem: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/wahoowriters.com

Comment: "It's been 3 days now" What did you change exactly 3 days ago? where? "Should it really be taking this long to propagate? " Propagation is a DNS myth or at least a very misused word. Your current entry has a TTL of 1 hour: changes should not take longer than that to appear (with many caveats that won't fit this comment box). "I just removed an AAAA record" that will not impact other resolutions nor IPv4 connectivity.